# Asp.NET Core cannot load font files generated by Vite Build

Tags: asp.net-core, build, vite, production-environment

I am integrating Asp.Net Core 6 and Vue 3 in a web project. 
"Vite Build" generated .js, .css and .woff2 file in wwwroot/dist folder.

In _layout.cshtml file, the following code works well to load .css and .js files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="~/dist/assets/main-*.css" />
<script type="module" asp-src-include="~/dist/assets/main-*.js"></script>
```

But files of awesome font in the same directory like fa-regular-400-8e7e5ea1.woff2 cannot be loaded.

I need your help to point what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding the following code in Program.cs.

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.WebRootPath, "dist/assets")),
            RequestPath = "/assets"
        });
```

Because the DevTools showed the link path as https://localhost:7159/assets/fa-solid-900-67a65763.ttf. But the file is saved in wwwroot/dist/assets.

Probably "Vite Build" has a bug that generated main-xxx.css with reference to wrong path as assets/font-file. It should point to dist/assets/font-file.